# Javascript table sort works well but iterating over all indexes gives different results

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have a table which I am sorting using the following function:

```
function ReorderSupplyGP(table){
  table.find('tr:not(.kn-table_summary)').sort(function (a, b) {
    var tda = $(a).find('td:eq(1)').text().trim();
    var tdb = $(b).find('td:eq(1)').text().trim();

    var sales = {
       "Purchase": 0, "Transfer": 1, "Returns": 2, "Adjustment": 3, "Inventory": 4
    };

    tda = sales[tda];
    tdb = sales[tdb]; 

    // if a < b return 1
    return tda > tdb ? 1
    // else if a > b return -1
    : tda < tdb ? -1
    // else they are equal - return 0    
    : 0;
  }).prependTo(table);


}
```

It works perfectly but when I print all the rows using function:

```
for(x=1;x<tablebodyrow.length;x++)
  {
    console.log(tablebodyrow.eq(x));
  }
```

It appears as if the rows were sorted visually but their index never changed. Is there a way to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thats exactly what you are doing:

1) you fill in some html table with values from some collection X
2) then you get html table, read values from its rows and reorder rows of html table
3) you dont reorder underlying collection anywhere

solutions:
1) reorder initial collection and re-render table
2) within your existing function reorder collection also, not just html table

Comment: that was a very stupid mistake :| ...thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: it happens...glad i could help:)